# Gracefully terminating timer based writer and go routine for reader process

Tags: go, goroutine

I have following code which contains:

- ticker based writer
- go routine for reading
- data channel for writer and reader communication
- stop_writer and stop_reader channels for stopping writer and reader gracefully
- signal handler in order to handle "Ctrl-C" user input

Code:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

func user_interupt_register() (writer_stop, reader_stop chan struct{}) {
    writer_stop = make(chan struct{}, 1)
    reader_stop = make(chan struct{}, 1)

    signal_channel := make(chan os.Signal)
    signal.Notify(signal_channel, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)

    go func() {
        for sig := range signal_channel {
            log.Println("Signal received: ", sig)
            reader_stop <- struct{}{}
            log.Println("Signal sent")
            break
        }

        close(signal_channel)
        log.Println("Closing User Interupt Register go routing")
    }()

    return writer_stop, reader_stop
}

func writer(item_id *uint32, data_channel chan uint32) {
    log.Println("[WRITER] Item ID: ", *item_id)
    data_channel <- *item_id
    *item_id++
}

func reader(reader_stop, writer_stop chan struct{}, data_channel chan uint32) {
    var flag = true
    for flag {
        select {
        case <-reader_stop:
            writer_stop <- struct{}{}
            flag = false
        case data, ok := <-data_channel:
            if ok {
                log.Println("[READER] Item ID: ", data)
            }
        default:
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
            log.Println("[READER] No ID to print")
            continue
        }
    }

    log.Println("About to close(reader_stop)")
    close(reader_stop)
    log.Println("close(reader_stop) finished")
}

func main() {
    log.Println("Starting Application")

    data_channel := make(chan uint32)
    defer close(data_channel)

    writer_stop, reader_stop := user_interupt_register()

    log.Println("Start Timer")
    ticker := time.NewTicker(2 * time.Second)

    go reader(reader_stop, writer_stop, data_channel)

    var item_id uint32
    item_id = 1

    var flag = true
    for flag {
        select {
        case <-ticker.C:
            writer(&item_id, data_channel)
        case <-writer_stop:
            log.Println("About to stop timer")
            ticker.Stop()
            log.Println("Timer stopped")
            flag = false
        }
    }

    log.Println("About to close(writer_stop)")
    close(writer_stop)
    log.Println("close(writer_stop) finished")
    log.Println("Exiting Application")
}
```

When I am stopping it occasionally I am getting following outputs:

```
2016/07/19 16:02:46 Starting Application
2016/07/19 16:02:46 Start Timer
2016/07/19 16:02:47 [READER] No ID to print
2016/07/19 16:02:48 [WRITER] Item ID:  1
2016/07/19 16:02:48 [READER] No ID to print
2016/07/19 16:02:48 [READER] Item ID:  1
2016/07/19 16:02:49 [READER] No ID to print
2016/07/19 16:02:50 [WRITER] Item ID:  2
2016/07/19 16:02:50 [READER] No ID to print
2016/07/19 16:02:50 [READER] Item ID:  2
2016/07/19 16:02:51 [READER] No ID to print
^C2016/07/19 16:02:52 Signal received:  interrupt
2016/07/19 16:02:52 Signal sent
2016/07/19 16:02:52 Closing User Interupt Register go routing
2016/07/19 16:02:52 [WRITER] Item ID:  3
2016/07/19 16:02:52 [READER] No ID to print
2016/07/19 16:02:52 About to close(reader_stop)
2016/07/19 16:02:52 close(reader_stop) finished
^Cpanic: send on closed channel

goroutine 5 [running]:
panic(0x4c1d00, 0xc8200980b0)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:481 +0x3e6
os/signal.process(0x7ffa8f64d078, 0xc8200980a0)
    /usr/local/go/src/os/signal/signal.go:176 +0x17a
os/signal.loop()
    /usr/local/go/src/os/signal/signal_unix.go:22 +0x75
created by os/signal.init.1
    /usr/local/go/src/os/signal/signal_unix.go:28 +0x37
```

However most of times it stops normally with following output.

```
2016/07/19 16:03:13 Starting Application
2016/07/19 16:03:13 Start Timer
2016/07/19 16:03:14 [READER] No ID to print
2016/07/19 16:03:15 [WRITER] Item ID:  1
2016/07/19 16:03:15 [READER] No ID to print
2016/07/19 16:03:15 [READER] Item ID:  1
2016/07/19 16:03:16 [READER] No ID to print
^C2016/07/19 16:03:16 Signal received:  interrupt
2016/07/19 16:03:16 Signal sent
2016/07/19 16:03:16 Closing User Interupt Register go routing
2016/07/19 16:03:17 [WRITER] Item ID:  2
2016/07/19 16:03:17 [READER] No ID to print
2016/07/19 16:03:17 [READER] Item ID:  2
2016/07/19 16:03:17 About to close(reader_stop)
2016/07/19 16:03:17 close(reader_stop) finished
2016/07/19 16:03:17 About to stop timer
2016/07/19 16:03:17 Timer stopped
2016/07/19 16:03:17 About to close(writer_stop)
2016/07/19 16:03:17 close(writer_stop) finished
2016/07/19 16:03:17 Exiting Application
```

So what is wrong? How can I be sure that it will stop normally stop all go routine and close channels?

Comment: Does it say on which line it is trying to write to closed channel? Can you add that information?

Answer (score 2):

IMO you should change your reader/writer structure. You do not need to stop the reader only the writer.

The problem with the current structure is that there might be items that will be written and never read. That is probably why you don't want to make data_channel a buffered channel. But still one item might not get read that was already written to the channel.

You only need a stop channel for the writer. The writer stops if that channel signals and closes the data channel. The reader has no select, just a `for item := range data_channel`. If the data_channel is closed, reader will empty the existing item(s) in it and stop by itself.

Replace this:

```
func reader(reader_stop, writer_stop chan struct{}, data_channel chan uint32) {
    var flag = true
    for flag {
        select {
        case <-reader_stop:
            writer_stop <- struct{}{}
            flag = false
        case data, ok := <-data_channel:
            if ok {
                log.Println("[READER] Item ID: ", data)
            }
        default:
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
            log.Println("[READER] No ID to print")
            continue
        }
    }

    log.Println("About to close(reader_stop)")
    close(reader_stop)
    log.Println("close(reader_stop) finished")
}
```

with:

```
func reader(writer_stop chan struct{}, data_channel chan uint32) {
    for item := range data_channel {
      log.Println("[READER] Item ID: ", data)
    }
}
```

Remove:

```
defer close(data_channel)
```

and add it here:

```
case <-writer_stop:
   close(data_channel)
   log.Println("About to stop timer")
   ticker.Stop()
   log.Println("Timer stopped")
   flag = false
```

Then you will need something that waits for the reader to finish. Check out `sync.WaitGroup`. Better way would be to put the writer in the go routine and put the reader in the main routine. That way your main routine will stop if the reader is done (which in turn stops if it doesn't receive any more values from the writer - by the writer closing the channel).

Here my working suggestion with as little changes as possible:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

func user_interupt_register() (writer_stop chan struct{}) {
    writer_stop = make(chan struct{}, 1)

    signal_channel := make(chan os.Signal)
    signal.Notify(signal_channel, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)

    go func() {
        for sig := range signal_channel {
            log.Println("Signal received: ", sig)
            writer_stop <- struct{}{}
            log.Println("Signal sent")
            break
        }

        close(signal_channel)
        log.Println("Closing User Interupt Register go routing")
    }()

    return
}

func writer(item_id *uint32, data_channel chan uint32, writer_stop chan struct{}) {
    log.Println("Start Timer")
    ticker := time.NewTicker(2 * time.Second)

    var flag = true
    for flag {
        select {
        case <-ticker.C:
            log.Println("[WRITER] Item ID: ", *item_id)
            data_channel <- *item_id
            *item_id++
        case <-writer_stop:
            close(data_channel)
            log.Println("About to stop timer")
            ticker.Stop()
            log.Println("Timer stopped")
            flag = false
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    log.Println("Starting Application")

    data_channel := make(chan uint32)

    writer_stop := user_interupt_register()

    var item_id uint32
    item_id = 1

    go writer(&item_id, data_channel, writer_stop)

    for data := range data_channel {
        log.Println("[READER] Item ID: ", data)
    }

    log.Println("About to close(writer_stop)")
    close(writer_stop)
    log.Println("close(writer_stop) finished")
    log.Println("Exiting Application")
}
```

You will not have the `log.Println("[READER] No ID to print")` message but otherwise it should produce the same result.

Note: the other code needs to be adjusted accordingly... like removing the writer_stop channel.

Comment: The OP uses the `flag` to terminate the loop, so he actually needs it :)

Comment: If I replace it with your suggestion I will not be able to write every 2 seconds.

Comment: @ain: oh yeah, didn't realize that. Could be done with `break`. @Phoenix: see my Note2 I just added to the answer.

Comment: But I cannot understand your Note2 at all. What do you mean reader reading every 2 second. I need writer to write every 2 second to reader. Break can be used with mark. But I prefer using with flag. It does not matter anyway.

Comment: @TehSphinX `data_channel` is written to, not read from. @Phoenix: What @TehSphinx probably mean is that you can adapt the range loop within the reader instead the write. So writer still writes every 3 seconds, but reader can now loop on `data_channel`. I still think issue lies with the way interrupt is being handled though.

Comment: @abhink: you are right, I mixed them up. Adjusted my answer.

Comment: @Phoenix: did this help? or is there anything I need to correct about my answer?

Answer (score 1):

What's happening in your code is that as soon as signal is sent, everything works until the end of the `reader` function. That is, signal is sent to `writer_stop` (statement `writer_stop <- struct{}{}` gets executed.

The problem is with your `select` in main. You are reading for a close value on `writer_stop` in a `case`.

```
    select {
    case <-ticker.C:
        writer(&item_id, data_channel)
    case <-writer_stop:
        log.Println("About to stop timer")
        ticker.Stop()
        log.Println("Timer stopped")
        flag = false
    }
```

Due to nature of `select`, if more than one `cases` are ready to be selected, `select` selects one at random.

Now in your `select` above, after the call to `writer_stop <- struct{}{}` has occurred, somehow due to erroneous synchronization, `case <-ticker.C:` is selected and `writer` gets called.

Since `reader` has returned at this point, and it was the only method reading from `data_channel`, `writer` blocks at `data_channel <- *item_id`, causing your program to hang.

The error `panic: send on closed channel` occurs because you hit `^C` again and the signal channel has been closed.

You can fix this in several way. One simple solution is to add buffer to data_channel:

```
data_channel := make(chan uint32, 1)
```

Here's one way to do this:

```
func user_interupt_register() (writer_stop, reader_stop chan struct{}) {
    writer_stop = make(chan struct{}, 1)
    // same as before

    go func() {
        sig := <-signal_channel
        writer_stop <- struct{}{} // change to writer_stop
        // same as before
    }()

    return writer_stop, reader_stop
}

func reader(data_channel chan uint32) {
    for item := range data_channel {
        log.Println("[READER] Item ID: ", item)
    }
}

func main() {
    log.Println("Starting Application")

    data_channel := make(chan uint32)
    // defer close(data_channel)

    writer_stop, _ := user_interupt_register()

    log.Println("Start Timer")
    ticker := time.NewTicker(2 * time.Second)
    readTicker := time.NewTicker(1 * time.Second)

    go reader(data_channel)

    go func() { // to print intermittent message
        for _ = range readTicker.C {
            data_channel <- 0 // some insignificant value
        }
    }()

    var item_id uint32 = 1

    for _ = range ticker.C {
        select {
        case <-writer_stop:
            data_channel <- item_id
            close(data_channel)
            ticker.Stop()
            readTicker.Stop()
            return
        default:
            data_channel <- item_id
            item_id++
        }
    }

    close(writer_stop)
}
```

Do note that this'll require a through testing.

Comment: Where informative thank you. However I cannot change data_channel in order to limit. For second solution can you explaining more? Because If i move write function to default section it will not write on given time. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @abhink: I don't understand. The error talks about sending on a closed channel. Its not hanging, is it?

Comment: @TehSphinX it is hanging. And when I hit second time "Ctrl-C" it panics.

Comment: Do you have to use timers to synchronize reading/writing? It is difficult to reason about behavior of the code with them. What is your actual use case?

Comment: @TehSphinX the code hangs. You can see a second `^C` just before the error used to stop the program. It's because the signal channel has been closed.

Comment: @abhink I should pull read from network every 5 secs. May be I should close ticker somewhere else?

Comment: @abhink: still this is not a clean solution in my opinion. For details why, see me answer.

Comment: @TehSphinX do you have some other suggestion?

Comment: @Phoenix: yes, see my answer.

Comment: Changing timer values don't affect synchronization issues generally. You might have to structure your code better.

Comment: BTW, creating a buffered channel wouldn't make much difference because your writes are still being limited. It's just that the last value read will be thrown away.

Comment: @abhink can give me some suggestion how I can re organize the code? Async programming drawing me mad.

Comment: @abhink I guess what I should is re organize code as following order. Start reader and after that writer. Uppon receiving interrupt signal i should first stop writer and then stop reader.

Comment: Correct, since reader is the consumer it depends upon the writer. Make sure that the writer never blocks and is gracefully closed off. Then you should be able to manage the reader properly.

Comment: @abhink Ok i will try to fix it. I am giving vote up for your answer. But sorry I cannot accept your answer. Since it is incomplete and does not contain working code. So if you will have time please update your answer accordingly. Thank you.

Comment: Added a working example. Although I'm still not sure if that's the best way to go about it. Would do some more thinking.